# how to get the google list of dangerous sites

Tags: delphi, malware, blacklist

I need to check the url against Google list of dangerous sites, how I do that for windows application ?

I will use Delphi.

thanks

Comment: If this is Windows and Delphi, it's probably not related to Google App Engine

Comment: You might want to tag this with "google" "malware" and "delphi" to have better chances at geting the answer to your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This site has information about the Google Safe Browsing API, which presumably will give you information about the list of malware sites.

http://code.google.com/apis/safebrowsing/developers_guide.html

Comment: what you suggest to use from components to make the http request from Delphi 

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I just write a entry on my blog about this subject check this link [`Using the Google Safe Browsing API from Delphi`](http://theroadtodelphi.wordpress.com/2011/07/11/using-the-google-safe-browsing-api-from-delphi/). in this article I explain how use the [`Safe Browsing Lookup API`](http://code.google.com/apis/safebrowsing/lookup_guide.html) which allow you to check a single o several url's at once using GET and POST requests.